# Unable to access Logger globally

Tags: python, python-3.6

In my project, I have two files:

1. main.py, and
2. methods.py

In **main.py**, which is the entry point, I have initialized logger as below:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
#Creating an object 
logger=logging.getLogger()
#Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG 
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

But I am unable to access it in **methods.py** which has a class with two methods. To make it work as of now, I am re-initializing logger in both the methods.

What I actually want is to initialize logger in **main.py**, and in the other file methods, I should be able to directly log:

```
logger.info('Triggered')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When giving the logger a name you can access it in multiple files:

```
#main.py
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
#Creating an object 
logger=logging.getLogger("my_logger")
#Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG 
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#methods.py
logger=logging.getLogger("my_logger")
logger.debug("Some log")
```